# How to get value of multiple UISlider in a single @IBAction?

Tags: swift, uislider, ibaction

I have 5 sliders that reference the same @IBAction func sliderDidSlide().  Each UISlider has a tag 0...4.  How do I get the value of each individual slider?  I wanted to use sender.tag to get which slider, then use .value to get its value.  I've tried sender.tag.value, but that doesn't work.

Below is what I want to do but it doesn't work.  I've tried searching but couldn't find a solution.  I know I could just have multiple @IBActions, but if possible I'd like to save code and use tags to put them all in the same @IBAction.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
@IBAction func sliderDidSlide(_ sender: UISlider) {
    
    let maxPrice = 10000

    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        let price = maxPrice * sender.tag.value // this doesn't work
        label1.text = "\(price)"
    case 1:
        // same idea as case 0
    case 2:
        <#code#>
    case 3:
        <#code#>
    case 4:
        <#code#>
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `sender.value`?

Comment: @Andrew is right. It should be `let price = maxPrice * sender.value`

Comment: @Andrew Normally I would use sender.value if there was a single UISlider attached to the IBAction.  However I have multiple sliders referencing the same IBAction, so I need a way to know which slider's value is changing.  That is why I use sender.tag.  I've tried: let price = Int(Float(maxPrice) * sender.value) but that also doesn't work.

Comment: @aheze I would normally use sender.value if there was only 1 UISlider attached to the IBAction.  However, I have 5 sliders in the same IBAction, which is why I need to use tags to know which sliders value is changing.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sliderDidSlide` will be called whenever one of the sliders' value changes. In each of those calls, the corresponding `UISlider` will be passed into the `sender` argument label.

You are already telling apart the sliders via the `switch sender.tag {`. `sender.tag.value` has no meaning, and won't compile, because `tag` does not have a property called `value`.

Once you've switched over the tags, you can directly access `sender.value`.

```
let price = maxPrice * sender.value /// directly access value

switch sender.tag {
case 0:
    label1.text = "\(price)"
case 1:
    label2.text = "\(price)
case 2:
    label3.text = "\(price)
case 3:
    label4.text = "\(price)
case 4:
    label5.text = "\(price)
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would do

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem as stated, but I dislike tags. They are fragile. If you later reorder your sliders, add more, remove some, or add other views that use the same tag numbers, your code can break (In this case you're fetching the tag from the sender, so you should not have a problem with duplicate tag numbers. `viewWithTag(_:)` is even **more** fragile.)

Comment: Instead of using tags I would suggest putting the sliders into an array and then finding the position in the array to figure out the correct index.